# triangles on right and left of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Looking to put buttons aligned to the right and left of the screen, Remaining there as the user scrolls (positioned absolute or fixed) then positioned relative when screen shrinks.

Big issue I want the text/icon in a white triangle (background) pointing inwards.

so far ...

```
<div id="bnav">
    <?php bnNav_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
</div>
```

css

```
[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous, 
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next { 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 50%; bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}

[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous { left: 0px; }
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next { right: 0px; } 

[class*="navigation"] .nav-previous a,
[class*="navigation"] .nav-next a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.75em; 
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.35s ease; 
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
}
```

the text is created dynamically through wordpress and put in div's labeled .nav-next and .nav-previous

Comment: not sure what you are asking.

Comment: You may fiddle it to show us what you did and as example of your problem.

Comment: i can never figure out the fiddle thing, made additions to my question. It works fine but just has a black box behind the 'a' link. I want a triangle instead